# Swift - CollectionViewCell Border Bug or Incomplete

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a collectionViewCell which appears to be weird.
The left,right vertical borders are missing, I don't know what I'm missing.
Can you help me guys? Thanks!

```
 public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! profileServicesCell

    // Card border
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor

    // Cell Content
    cell.profileServiceName.text = profileServicesName[indexPath.row]
    cell.profileServiceIcon.image = UIImage(named: profileServicesIcon[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}
```

Attached images for reference :

**StoryBoard Image**

[image: StoryBoard Image]

**Simulator/RunTime**

[image]

Comment: Probably layout issue. Try changing the width of item from the delegate method

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem that you didn't specify any size for your cell try this out :

```
extension Your_Class :  UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = self.view.frame.width * 0.4  // or whatever width you like 
    let height = width / 2 // or whatever height you like 
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
  }

   }
```